# Use google analytics filters to identify an event

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

There are two events:

e1. eventCategory: A
    eventAction: B
totalEvents=20

e2. eventCategory: C
    eventAction: B
totalEvents=30

I queried totalEvents using filter ( `ga:eventCategory==A; ga:eventAction==B` ), the result is 25.

What's the problem, how can I get the totalEvents of event e1 (to get the result of 20)?

Comment: Why do you want 1? Wouldn't you want 20?

Comment: @sdhaus Yes, I want to get the result of 20